# How to import data form lists in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a program that takes 3 different inputs and stores them in 3 separate lists and then be able to combine them in a dictionary and print on screen.

So far I got this :

```
size = input("Enter size of family: ")
names = []
year = []
address= []
for i in range(int(size)):
    print("Enter name: ", end=' ')
    names.append(input())
    print("Enter birthyear: ", end=' ')
    year.append(int(input()))
    print("Enter address: ", end=' ')
    address.append(str(input()))

d = list(zip(names, year, address))
print(d)
```

Comment: There's no need to call `str()`, `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: Why do you need the lists in the first place? Just add to the dictionary in the loop. But if you must: `d = dict(zip(names, zip(year, address)))`

Comment: In the loop you could do `d[name] = {"year": year, "address": address}`

Comment: BTW, normally you put the prompt in the argument to `input()`, not a separate `print()`, e.g. `input("Enter address: ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this code quite a bit:

```
size = int(input("Enter size of family: "))
family_data = {}

for i in range(size):
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    birthyear = int(input("Enter birthyear: "))
    address = input("Enter address: ")

    family_data[name] = {'birthyear': birthyear, 'address': address}

print(family_data)
```